# How can I enable the wireless access in Lenovo?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

In a Lenovo G585 with Windows 8 installed, I can not connect to Wi-Fi networks. 
I see that there is no button to turn on the Wi-Fi. 
After googling I found that Lenovo's don't offer such a button and I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. 
Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, I see the option to enable Airplane Mode On/Off and it says that there is no wireless access enabled but there is no option to connect to a network. 
I checked BIOS and the Wi-Fi access is on.  I can connect to the internet with cable only.

Is this a known issue for Lenovo? 
How can I enable the wireless access in Lenovo?

Comment: Did you check your device manager? under network adapters do u see any question marks? Is the hardware available in the first place?

Comment: @Prasanna:I see an exclamation mark (in yellow background) next to `WAN Miniport (IP)`, `WAN Miniport (IPv6)` and `WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)`. The rest seem OK. Does this show an issue?

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Lenovo-G585-Wireless-Network-Issue/td-p/930559. In this forum see the post of "TechManCan"

Comment: Turning Airplane Mode on disables all wireless functions, including BlueTooth and WiFi: make sure it is off. The electronic manual on my G580 has a page describing what requires to be done. I will be surprised if your G585 does not have equivalent documentation.

Comment: @AFH:The mode is off.But it is the only thing I can configure if I press `Fn+F5`.The manual says that pressing these keys I should be able to see the networks but I can't.

Comment: I guess you'll have to check the community support, as provided in the link from @Prasanna.

Comment: If you get desperate, you can try booting an Ubuntu Live CD from USB pen-drive to see if you get connectivity there. This will at least verify the hardware. There are also Windows-based diagnostic discs, but I have not tried WiFi on the G580 with these, so I cannot say if failure of WiFi would indicate a hardware problem.

Comment: or try this Youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHGSgCmyeXw&src_vid=vvoNgUqXduQ&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_2314366887 - if you haven't tried this before

Comment: @AFH:My mistake.It is Windows 8.I always confuse this

Comment: @Prasanna:Something strange.I just noticed that the F5 has only an airplane icon and none of the F buttons have an icon that indicates wifi as in your video.Trying to update the wireless adapter driver it said that I have the latest software installed

Comment: @Jim - I was mildly surprised when you said you had W7, as my G580 came with W8. Unfortunately I can't get into it (any attempt to boot or recover gives UEFI errors), so I can't check what happens in Windows when I turn Airplane Mode off and on. For what it's worth it works as I would expect in Ubuntu, exactly like turning Wireless off and on with earlier laptops.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> not working]

I faced the issue of Wi-Fi not being enabled in May 2016 (suddenly <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> stopped working and I could not reenable the Wi-Fi on my Lenovo Y580) after many of the forum posts had been written. None of the proposed solutions I came across solved my problem.

Now I found a solution and am here to share it:

1. Go to Lenovo support page http://support.lenovo.com/br/en/ and select your laptop (mine was IdeaPad Y series (ideapad) Y580 model bought back in 2012)
2. select your operating system (mine is Windows 7 (64-bit))
3. download and install the BIOS update

I don't know why, but flashing (updating) the BIOS worked, once computer restarted <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> worked again, as well as the "A" symbol on the screen when <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> was pressed started appearing again as well.

Below I will list all the things I tried from forum and Lenovo pages to solve the problem that did not solve it (but may solve your problem in case updating the BIOS won't do):

- Going on Control Panel/Network and Internet/Change adapter Settings and enabling the Intel wireless connection: Windows cannot enable it, it actually recommends you use a physical switch or use function keys when you use the "diagnosys" function.
- Going on <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> \msconfig\startup and enabling all "Startup Item"s named "Lenovo ...". (Strangely, my "startup" list does not contain "Lenovo Utility" item as I have seen on the internet, not even now when all is working well.)
- Going on BIOS (restarting computer and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> when Lenovo icon appears) and disabling the Wireless connection, then restarting, going on BIOS again and enabling the Wireless connection.
- Uninstaling and installing again the other software for download at the support page for my laptop model, "Lenovo Onekey Recovery" and "Power Management", or installing the "HotFix" listed there.
- Plugging my computer to a monitor, using "extended option" to extend desktop to both screens (laptop and monitor) and trying <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. 
  (I thought the dialog box was opening on a hidden area of the desktop as I sometimes use a monitor.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BIOS,
enter security,
Select device security,
Choose I/O Port access. Enable it.
Exit bios.
Restart your system.
Your WLAN should work  now